# Standard Quotation Format in MLA

Tags: quotations, mla

If I were to have a quote and there were a contraction in it, would I need to put brackets around the de-contracted word or can I just de-contract it.

For example: He said, "I'll go to the store tomorrow."

Would I de-contract it the first or second way in MLA format?

"[I will] go to the store tomorrow."

or

"I will go to the store tomorrow."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on Writers Stack Exchange:  'According to the closing of my question, it seems the Writers Stack Exchange is the proper place for questions about style guides and style usage.'
Jun 26 '11 at 13:27  Ricket // My opinion is that specific requests for single-style-guide rulings do not address the language in an objective way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't de-contract it, as the contracted form is perfectly valid and understandable. But if I did expand out a contraction or acronym I would use [].

Note that if something was said in speech, the [] is not needed as it can validly be expanded as normal speech always leaves bits out (elides things) and we are not usually even aware of this. If the non-standard contraction is retained it is for effect.  If a non-native speaker uses something in appropriate the choice is leave it (and mark it with *sic*) or replace it (and mark it with []) or rewrite it as an indirect quotation (and mark this by omitting the "").

"I wanna go to the store tomorrow".

in speech --> text for the first time "I want to go to the store tomorrow"

in text --> corrected text for MLA "I [want to] go to the store tomorrow"
in text --> sicced text for MLA "I wanna (sic) go to the store tomorrow"

but the [] still seems a bit pedantic, and the (sic) a bit rude, to me personally.

I would either leave it or expand it without mark up if I had to have it as a quote, and if I had to have it, it means the form is important and I would leave it.  Otherwise I would make it an indirect quote.

Comment: Speaking of pedantic, MLA specifies that *sic* appear in [brackets] inside a quotation and in (parentheses) outside.

Comment: @deadrat Surely that is to distinguish _sic_'s already in the quotes and reproduced from those added to the quotes on quoting (so both sorts could appear in the quote).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had to stare at your comment for a long time before I understood it.  At least, I think I finally understood it.  Please tell me that *reproduced* doesn't go with *from*.  But, no, I don't think the enclosers indicate who sicc'd which on whom.

Comment: Surely that is to distinguish {sic's already in the quotes and reproduced} from {those added to the quotes on quoting} (so both sorts could appear in the quote). Is the sic part of the quoted material, or has it been appended to the quote by the quoter.